# Slide in on Hover, Slide out on Leave

Tags: jquery

I have a contact form that I would like to slide out when a mouse hovers over the button, and make the form stay as long as the mouse is hovering over `.hoverclass` (The button and the form itself). However, I've accomplished in making it do weird stuff instead.

[Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/jnzsm2L0/)

```
<div id="contact-wrapper">
    <div class="floating-contact-inner hoverclass" id="floating-contact-wrap">
        <div id="contact-btn" class="hoverclass">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="floating-contact" >
            <!-- Lalala  -->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var floatbox = jq("#floating-contact-wrap");    

jq('.hoverclass').hover(
   function(e){
       if (!jq(floatbox).hasClass('visiable')){
           floatbox.animate({"right":"-294px"}, "slow").addClass('visiable');
       }
   },
   function(e){
     floatbox.animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow").removeClass('visiable');
   }
);
```

Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jnzsm2L0/7/)** - If the hover event makes the element visible, switching the order of the callbacks will produce what you're looking for,`hover(in, out)`. Using jQuery [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function prevents the animation stutter.

```
floatbox.hover(
    function(e){
        floatbox.stop(true).animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow");
    },
    function(e){
        floatbox.animate({"right":"-294px"}, "slow");        
    }
);
```

This eliminates the need for adding and removing classes and relies on `hover` to determine it's state

Comment: try hovering fast on and off and see how the animation doesn't get buggy.

Comment: I would also put a stop on the second handler. To prevent the need to fully display the control before it slides back out (for those times when you hover the handle by accident).

Answer (score 0):

May have them into mouseover and mouseleave functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/jnzsm2L0/8/

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

var floatbox = jq("#floating-contact-wrap");
floatbox.mouseover(

function (e) {
    if (!jq(floatbox).hasClass('visible')) {
        floatbox.stop(true).animate({
            "right": "0px"
        }, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
});

floatbox.mouseleave(

function (e) {
    if (jq(floatbox).hasClass('visible')) {
        floatbox.animate({
            "right": "-294px"
        }, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's buggy, try to hover in and out of the control fast enough, the result is not interesting.

Comment: @Yan Brunet you're right, should add stop(true) to perform explicit single animation, thanks.